# Как отправить фото через web app telegram

Tags: reactjs, node.js, telegram

Пишу фронт на react для telegram web app, мне нужно отправить фото, которое загружается на открывающейся странице, но я никак не могу понять как это сделать. Я отправляю не только фото, но еще и обычные строки, с этим у меня проблем нет, но фото не отправляется, пробовал делать FormData и отправлять ее, но она не приходит.

```
    const tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
    const Form = () => {
    const [name , setName] = useState();
    const [problem , setProblem] = useState();
    const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null);
  

    const onSendData = useCallback(() => {
        
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('photo',photo);
        
        
        const data = {
            name,
            problem,
        }
        
        tg.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, [name,problem,photo])

    useEffect(() => {
        tg.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', onSendData);
        return () =>{
            tg.offEvent('mainButtonClicked', onSendData);
        }
    }, [onSendData])

    useEffect(() => {
        tg.MainButton.setParams({
            text: 'Отправить данные'
        })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!name || !problem){
            tg.MainButton.hide();
        }else{
            tg.MainButton.show();
        }
    },[name,problem])

    const onChangeName = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
    }

    const onChangeProblem = (e) => {
        setProblem(e.target.value);
    }
    const onChangePhoto = (e) => {
        setPhoto(e.target.files[0]);
        
    }

    return (
        <div className={'form__wrapper'}>
            <div className={'container'}>
                <form action="" className={'form'}>
                    <h2 className={'form__title'}>Проблема с товаром</h2>
                    <input type="text" placeholder={'Название товара'} className={'form__input form__input-name'} value={name} onChange={onChangeName}/> 
                    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder='Опишите проблему' className={'form__textarea'} value={problem} onChange={onChangeProblem}></textarea>
                    <h3 className={'form__title-img'}>Вы можете загрузить фотографию</h3>
                    <input type='file' accept="image/*,.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" onChange={onChangePhoto}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Код из бота, который принимает отправленную data:

```
if (msg?.web_app_data?.data){
    try{
        const data = JSON.parse(msg?.web_app_data?.data);
        console.log(data);
        await bot.sendMessage(chatId,'Спасибо за обратную связь')
        await bot.sendMessage(chatId,'Имя товара ' + data?.name);
        await bot.sendMessage(chatId,'Проблема ' + data?.problem);
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
```